# Does a Google Map element have to be in the DOM when instantiating?

Tags: google-maps, dom, google-maps-api-3

I am instantiating a Google Map object like so:

```
this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.el, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoom: this.zoom
});
```

Where `this.el` is an object created via `document.createElement('div')` but has not yet been inserted into the DOM.  When I later append `this.el` to the DOM I get a map that looks like this (note all the weird gray space):

http://cl.ly/3B3z1e3g2h1U301r0X1R

I do not have this problem, though, if I first append `this.el` to the DOM and then instantiate the map object.  Is there a way to create the map and then append it?  This would greatly simplify some of my map code (I am using this in Backbone.js views).

Thanks.

-Scott

Comment: Same comment from a similar question: If you are using MarionetteJS with regions, creating the map inside the onShow method rather than onRender solves the problem, as the view is already in the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you append this.el to the DOM, you have to call google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, 'resize');

Comment: ...because the API believes it still to have no size, so you need to tell it otherwise.